# How to know which RRD file is being written to?

Tags: rrdtool, cacti

I am a newbie to Cacti, so please excuse my naivity here. I would like to gather the SNMP data collected via the data template 'Interface Highspeed Statistics' (interface_highspeed.xml, as defined in $CACTI_HOME/resources/snmp_queries). I can click my way around Cacti GUI, and after having made sure that the above XML file is listed as a Data Collection method:

1. Go to 'Create Graphs', and choose a router,
2. Click on Graph Types, and select 'SNMP HighSpeed Interface Statistics'

to get the result. I want to know if:

1. There is an API to do this?
2. Or, alternatively, know which RRD file does this create, so that I can use rrdtool dump or fetch command to get the contents in XML format, that I can then parse in my data analysis application (which is completely separate from Cacti, and is written in Python).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
trupsster

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the graph.
2. click on the tool or spanner button.
3. Check the DEF: /var/lib/cacti/rra/rra-file:AVERAGE